# How to integer-divide round negative numbers *down*?

Tags: c#, c++

Seems like whenever I divide a negative int by a positive int, I need it to round *down* (toward -inf), not toward 0. But both C# and C++ round toward 0.

So I guess I need a DivideDownward() method. I can write it in a few lines with a test for negative and so on, but my ideas seem klugey. So I'm wondering if I'm missing something and if you have an "elegant" way to round negative division downward.

Comment: Give examples of the behavior you want.

Comment: Example? OK, I need (-5)/3 to yield -2, not -1. But I really don't think the example adds anything to the (IMO) clear question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: this post produces incorrect results for input with a=-1. Please see other answers.**

---

[c++]

This is probably what you meant by 'kludgey', but it's what I came up with.

```
int divideDown(int a, int b){
    int r=a/b;
    if (r<0 && r*b!=a)
        return r-1;
    return r;
}
```

In the if statement, I put r<0 - however I'm not sure if that's what you want. You may wish to change the if statement to

```
if (a<0 && b>0)
```

which would be consistent with your description "Seems like whenever I divide a **negative int by a positive int** ".

Comment: This *is* what I meant by klugey, but I don't know anything better. Especially for the r*b!=a test, which is probably more efficient than a%b!=0, and justifies the extra lines of code as compared to the single-line expressions offered, I award this "the answer".

Comment: I'm not certain about this, but shouldn't it be `if (r<=0 && r*b!=a)`?

Comment: It's worse than that -- as written, this produces the wrong answer for a=-1, and if you change it to r<=0, then it produces the wrong answer for a=1.  This answer should not have been accepted; it produces incorrect results.

Comment: Cannot delete as it is the accepted answer. Will try to fix with a solution, but until then have edited with a warning. Thanks for finding the bug!

Comment: @Cam I thought it was possible to delete your own answer even if it is already accepted. In fact, I thought there was some sort of self critic badge for doing so. Maybe not.

Answer (score 11):

> Whenever I divide a negative int by a positive int, I need it to round *down*.

It's hell, isn't it?  Knuth wrote why this is the right way to do things, but we're stuck with legacy integer hardware.

- If you can afford the loss of precision, the simplest and cleanest way to do this is to cast a 32-bit integer to a 64-bit `double` and use the FP rounding mode to round toward minus infinity when you convert the quotient back to integer.  Today's floating-point units are pretty fast and may actually divide *faster* than an integer unit; to be sure, you'd have to measure.
- If you need full 64-bit integer precision, I've dealt with this problem as a compiler writer by doing the two conditional branches so that you wind up dividing the magnitudes, then get the correct sign.  But this was a while back when the conditional branch was cheap compared to a divide; on today's hardware, I would have to experiment before I'd be able to recommend something.
- In principle, you could pull the floating-point trick on 64-bit ints by using the legacy Intel 80-bit floating-point numbers, but it's wildly unportable, and I don't trust Intel to keep making that unit fast.  These days the floating point speed is in the SSE unit.
- Places to look for other tricks would include Hank Warren's book [*Hacker's Delight*](http://hackersdelight.org) (my copy is at work) and the [MLton](http://mlton.org/) compiler for Standard ML, which requires integer division to round toward minus infinity.

Whatever you do, when you get settled on it, if you are using C++ or C99, stick your divide routine into a .h file and make it `static inline`.  That way when your solution turns out to be suboptimal for new whizbang hardware delivered in 5 years, you have one place to change it.

Comment: I thought int32 -> double wouldn't lose any precision. But I just optimized some fp code where fstp ops (on near-0 numbers) were taking most of my CPU time. Maybe not relevant, but I'm soured on unnecessary fp for now. ;)

Answer (score 11):

You can get rid of any branching by doing this:

```
inline int DivideRoundDown(int a_numerator, int a_denominator)
{
    return (a_numerator / a_denominator) + ((a_numerator % a_denominator) >> 31);
}
```

Comment: Does this function take any assumptions, or does it work for all combinations of positive/negative operands?

Comment: @cubuspl42 Relies on `a/b` giving the same sign as `a%b` – not sure if guaranteed by the standard but I think all modern compilers/hardware do so – relies, too, on signed right-shift being arithmetical (if that or logical, if I recall correctly, even today – and yes, I know I'm >10 years late, but there might other late readers, too… – still is implementation defined, though all compilers/hardware I'm aware of shift arithmetically) – and finally relies on `int` having 32 bits, which definitely is not the case on every machine (there are MCU with smaller `int`).

Comment: (The last requirement can be easily eliminated by having `>> sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1`.)

Answer (score 10):

Assuming b is always positive, here is a cheap solution:

```
inline int roundDownDivide(int a, int b) {
  if (a >= 0) return a/b; 
  else return (a-b+1)/b;
}
```

Comment: `roundDownDivide(-2147483648, 2) == 1073741823` -- it overflows if `a < INT_MIN + b - 1`, while at the same time not being the fastest. See my answer for detailed evaluation.

Answer (score 8):

If you wanted to write this just using integers in a relatively succinct way, then you can write this:

```
var res = a / b - (a % b < 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

This probably compiles to quite a few instructions, but it may still be faster than using floating-points.

Comment: The OP didn't mention C, but it's still worth noting this is not guaranteed to work in C89 due to implementation-defined %.  I think you can generalize it by changing to `a % b != 0`.

Comment: @Matthew: That's tricky. However, it needs to return 0 if `a % b` returns a number larger than zero (so that's why I need `<` in C#).

Comment: @Tom, good point.  I was thinking in terms of `a` being negative.  So I guess a generalized version would be: `a /b - (a < 0 && a % b != 0 ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: I think the given answer is implementation-dependent, but Matthew's modification appears concise and reliable. If it was an answer I'd checkmark it. Thank you (everyone)!

Comment: @Matthew: actually, this is guarenteed to work by both C89 and C99 -- they require that `(a/b)*b + a%b == a` unless `b == 0` even though the actual values returned by `/` and `%` are implementation defined for negative operands.  Your version will fail if the builtin / rounds towards -inf instead of 0.

Comment: @Chris: At least by MS docs, in both C# and C++ / rounds toward 0, not -inf.

Comment: @Chris, you're right.  I forgot that `/` was also implementation-defined in C89.

Comment: This produces **INCORRECT RESULTS** if `b` is negative. For example, `-1 / -2` is computing `-1` rather than `0`.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: I posted a version that works for negative `b` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Many programming languages, including the older standards of C and C++, guarantee the division rule, which is

```
a = b * (a / b) + a % b
```

even if the exact values of `a/b` and `a%b` are left undefined.<sup>[0]</sup> This can be exploited to calculate the desired result in many languages and platforms using (an equivalent of) the following code:

```
int divF(int a, int b) { return a / b - (a % b < 0); }
```

This is the version from @TomasPetricek's answer. However, it works only for `b > 0`!

The following code works for any `b != 0`:<sup>[[1]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.74.8522&rep=rep1&type=pdf)</sup>

```
int sign(int x) { return (x > 0) - (x < 0); }
int divF2(int a, int b) { return a / b - (sign(a % b) == -sign(b)); }
```

However, the rounding-down division (aka **flooring division**, aka **Knuth's division**) is not always desirable. It is argued<sup>[[2]](https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/314490/file/452146.pdf)</sup> that Euclidean division is the most generally useful one. It rounds down for `b > 0`, and up for `b < 0`. It has the nice property that the value of the compatibly defined remainder is *always non-negative*, for all `a` and `b`, independently of their signs. Additionally it coincides with bit-shifts and masking on twos complement machines for power-of-two divisors. Yes, it is also faster to calculate:

```
int divE(int a, int b) {
    int c = a % b < 0;
    return a / b + (b < 0 ? c : -c);
}
```

All three versions generate branchless code with clang `-O3` on amd64. However, on twos complement architectures, the following *may* be marginally faster:

```
int divE2(int a, int b) { return a / b + (-(a % b < 0) & (b < 0 ? 1 : -1)); }
```

### Generated code

```
divF:
    cdq
    idiv    esi
    sar edx, 31
    add eax, edx

divF2:
    cdq
    idiv    esi
    xor ecx, ecx
    test    edx, edx
    setg    cl
    sar edx, 31
    add edx, ecx
    xor ecx, ecx
    test    esi, esi
    setg    cl
    shr esi, 31
    sub esi, ecx
    xor ecx, ecx
    cmp edx, esi
    sete    cl
    sub eax, ecx

Chazz:
    cdq
    idiv    esi
    test    edx, edx
    cmove   edi, esi
    xor edi, esi
    sar edi, 31
    add eax, edi

divE:
    cdq
    idiv    esi
    mov ecx, edx
    shr ecx, 31
    sar edx, 31
    test    esi, esi
    cmovs   edx, ecx
    add eax, edx

divE2:
    cdq
    idiv    esi
    sar edx, 31
    shr esi, 31
    lea ecx, [rsi + rsi]
    add ecx, -1
    and ecx, edx
    add eax, ecx
```

### Benchmarks

```
simple truncating division:
    2464805950:  1.90 ns -- base

euclidean division:
    2464831322:  2.13 ns -- divE
    2464831322:  2.13 ns -- divE2

round to -inf for all b:
    1965111352:  2.58 ns -- Chazz
    1965111352:  2.64 ns -- divF2
    1965111352:  5.02 ns -- Warty

round to -inf for b > 0, broken for b < 0:
    1965143330:  2.13 ns -- ben135
    1965143330:  2.13 ns -- divF
    1965143330:  2.13 ns -- Tomas
    4112595000:  5.79 ns -- runevision

round to -inf, broken for b < 0 or some edge-cases:
    4112315315:  2.24 ns -- DrAltan
    1965115133:  2.45 ns -- Cam
    1965111351:  7.76 ns -- LegsDrivenCat
```

Compiled with clang `-O3` on FreeBSD 12.2, i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz. The first column is a checksum grouping algorithms producing the same result. `base` is the simplest truncating division used to measure the testing overhead.

The test-bed:

```
static const int N = 1000000000;
int rng[N][2], nrng;
void push(int a, int b) { rng[nrng][0] = a, rng[nrng][1] = b, ++nrng; }
SN_NOINLINE void test_case(int (*func)(), const char *name) {
    struct timespec t0, t1;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROF, &t0);
    int sum = func();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROF, &t1);
    double elapsed = (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec)*1.e9 + (t1.tv_nsec - t0.tv_nsec);
    printf("%10u: %5.2f ns -- %s\n", sum, elapsed/N, name);
}

#define ALL_TESTS(X) X(base) X(divF) X(divF2) X(divE) X(divE2) X(ben135) X(DrAltan) X(Cam) X(Tomas) X(Warty) X(Chazz) X(runevision) X(LegsDrivenCat)

#define LOOP_TEST(X) \
    SN_NOINLINE int loop_##X() { \
        int sum = 0; \
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) sum += X(rng[i][0], rng[i][1]); \
        return sum; \
    } \
/**/
ALL_TESTS(LOOP_TEST)

int main() {
    srandom(6283185);
    push(INT_MAX, 1); push(INT_MAX, -1); push(INT_MIN, 1);
    push(INT_MAX, 2); push(INT_MAX, -2); push(INT_MIN, 2); push(INT_MIN, -2);
    while(nrng < N) {
        int a = random() - 0x40000000, b;
        do b = (random() >> 16) - 0x4000; while(b == 0);
        push(a,b);
    }

#define CALL_TEST(X) test_case(loop_##X, #X);
    ALL_TESTS(CALL_TEST)
}
```

### Footnotes/references

0. Nowadays they are defined in C and C++ to round by truncation. So negatives are rounded upwards, positives downwards. This is what hardware divisors do. This is a bummer, cause it's the least useful rounding rule.
1. [Daan Leijen. Division and Modulus for Computer Scientists. December 2001.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.74.8522&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
2. [Raymond T. Boute. The Euclidean definition of the functions div and mod. April 1992.](https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/314490/file/452146.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that works when the divisor is negative:

```
int floor_div2(int a, int b)
{
  int rem = a % b;
  int div = a/b;
  if (!rem)
    a = b;
  int sub = a ^ b;
  sub >>= 31;
  return div+sub;
}
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution on this page, based on my benchmarks, that gives the correct result for all edge-cases. Huge +1 from me.

Comment: @YakovGalka "gives the correct result for all edge-cases."  `floor_div2(INT_MIN, -1)` leads to trouble with `a/b`.  Fails when size of `int` is not 32.  Relies on 2's complement - which is usually these days.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it actually does the right thing for INT_MIN/-1. Let's not nit-pick the hardcoded 31 -- anybody can fix it and the algorithm doesn't rely on the size of int. As for 2's complement -- it is ubiquitous these days.

Comment: @YakovGalka In the C/C++, `INT_MIN/-1` is _undefined behavior_.  That it worked for you is not specified by the language to work for all.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i know what it is; my point is that `floor_div2` behaving the same way as the built-in division in this case is what i would expect from such a function of doing.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Floor((double)a/(double)b)`
if you need it as an int, cast it afterwards
`(int)Math.Floor((double)a/(double)b)`

Comment: `decimal` is the [slowest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx) numeric type, and it doesn't add anything here.  `float` or `double` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You also don't need to cast the denominator, just the numerator.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: I was considering that.  I did not realize the int he was talking about was an int32.  If you plug in the extraneous values for a and b [Int64.MaxValue-1 and Int64.MaxValue respectively], using double will break because of floating point error, and you'll get 1 instead of 0.  Answer has been fixed.

Comment: This answer works, but given the performance cost of fp, I'd consider it no improvement over my "kludgey" method ideas.

Answer (score 2):

For powers of 2, depending on your compiler implementation ([Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx)), you could use a right shift.

```
-5 >> 2 == -2
```

Answer (score 1):

Dr Atlans solution above is the most general answer, but if you know that a isn't going to be less than some fixed number, you can add the smallest multiple of b that will make it positive and then adjust the result.  For example, if a is always >= -10 * b, you can say:

```
return (a + 10 * b) / b - 10
```

or if you just want a correct result when a is positive or 0 and *some* negative result when a is negative (eg for testing if the result is >= 0 without including the range a = [-1 ; -b +1]) you can do

```
return (a + b) / b - 1;
```

which will return -1 for [-1 , -b + 1] as well as for [-b ; -2 * b + 1], but that doesn't matter if you're just trying establish if the result of the division is positive.  Effectively we're just changing the rounding so that it rounds towards -1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in low-level optimization, but here's a version with no branching (conditionals) which also doesn't require conversions to floating point numbers. Tested in C#, it seems to be significantly faster there than the versions using branching.

```
return (a - (((a % b) + b) % b)) / b;
```

This solution is partially derived from the discussions about how to do the best modulo function for negative numbers: [Modulo of negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417183/modulo-of-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** My solution didn't work in all cases. Here's a C# implementation of [Dr.Atlan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4168996/65387) solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// Divides a/b, rounding negative numbers towards -Inf.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="a">Dividend</param>
/// <param name="b">Divisor; must be positive for correct results</param>
/// <returns>a ÷ b</returns>
public static int Div(int a, int b)
{
    return a < 0 ? (a - b + 1) / b : a / b;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for numbers that can be divided without remainder. For example, `Div(-1, 1)` returns -2.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Hah! That explains the artifacts in my game. Using Dr.Altan's solution instead now; that one seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Do the calculation in an unsigned long by offsetting with 2^31, eg:

```
int floor_div(int a, int b)
{
  unsigned long aa = a + (1UL << 31);
  unsigned long cc = (aa / b) - (1UL << 31);
  return (int)cc
}
```

I have not tested this.

Comment: `floor_div(6, 2) == -1431655764`? O.o This guy deserves the "most broken solution on this page" badge.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way (only one division, no multiplication, no modulo, looks like fastest solution):

```
(a < 0 && b > 0) ? (a - b + 1) / b : (a > 0 && b < 0) ? (a - b - 1) / b : a / b
```

I was curious what is faster: less branching or less multiplications/divisions/modulos, so I compared my solution with **runevision**'s one and in this particular case less divisions is better than less branching.
**ben135**'s solution gives incorrect results in some cases (e.g. 10/-3 gives -3 but should be -4).

Answer (score -1):

From the top of my head, completely untested because I am typing on my phone. Feedback appreciated.

```
/// Integer division with rounding towards negative infinity.
static inline int div_(int a, int b)
{
    // Only one division. No modulo. No multiplication. Minimal or no branching.
    int a_ = abs(a);
    int b_ = abs(b);
    int r = (a<0)^(b<0) // Differing signs?
        ? -((a_+b_/2)/b_) // Negative away from zero.
        : a_/b_; // Positive toward zero.
    return r;
}
```